# Outputting HTML from a PHP function works with Print_r but not with echo

Tags: php

I know that `print_r` prints arrays and objects and `echo` does the rest.

My questions is a result of me coding something and somehow the returned variable of a `function` does not print with `echo` but it does with `print_r` or `var_dump`. I am very pron to believe that this result is a problem with my code rather than a difference between `echo` and `print_r` given that the returned variable is a `string` not an `array`

So my question is as follows: Why the `function showPreviousDiscipline` only displays the HTML code that it returnt if I put `print_r` in the template? Shouldn't it display only by me calling the function without the need of `echo` or `print_r`? at the end of the day is just text what is outputing

The HTML

```
<div class="ldcMainWrap">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select multiple="multiple" size="5"> 
            <?php 
// Displays something in the page if is print_r but not if i echo it... or even if i dont put anything...
print_r ($this->showPreviousDiscipline(1)); 
?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select multiple="multiple" size="5"> 
            </select>
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
<div>
```

THE PHP

```
public function drawWebsite () {
    $tpl = include "step.one.view.php";
    return $tpl;
}

public function showPreviousDiscipline ( $uID ) {   
    $AllUserDetails = parent::$this->pullUserDetails ( $uID );
    $allDataRaw     = parent::$this->pullDeparmentTableData ();
    $html       = '';

    // Loops through the array $allDataRaw
    foreach ($allDataRaw as $key => $val) { 

        foreach ($val  as $key2 => $val2) {

            //CHECKs if he user has already selected one and if it does it applies a CSS class
            if($key2) {
                if($val2 === $AllUserDetails['rID']) {
                    $html .= '<option value ="'.$val2.'" class="selected">'.$key2.'</option>';
                }else {
                    $html .= '<option value ="'.$val2.'" class="unselected">'.$key2.'</option>';}
            }
        }   
    }   
    $html           .= ''; 
    return $html;
}
```

TEST OUTPUT

```
        <select multiple="multiple" size="5"> 
  <option value="11" class="unselected">dID</option>
    <option value="test1" class="unselected">dName</option>
    <option value="" class="unselected">dDescription</option>
<option value="22" class="selected">dID</option>
    <option value="test2" class="unselected">dName</option>
    <option value="" class="unselected">dDescription</option> 
               </select>
```

Comment: Could you put some test data in the question? I tried some cases and `echo` works.

Comment: Your `showPreviousDiscipline()` method doesn't "show" anything, it just returns a string containing HTML.

Comment: `parent::$this->pullDeparmentTableData ();` is afaic wrong - it should just be `parent::pullDeparmentTableData();`.

Comment: @JonathanThurft I mean `$AllUserDetails` and `$allDataRaw`. I tried `$AllUserDetails = ['1'=>'c', '2' => 'b'];$allDataRaw     = [['1'=> 'c', '2'=>'a']];`, and `echo` works.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

```
echo (unlike some other language constructs) does not behave like a function,    
so it cannot always be used in the context of a function.
```

So echo( fn()) will return NULL. If you want to 'echo' the value of your function you need to return the value into some local var and echo that value. Either that or (as you found) call it via 'print_r'.

Per your question:

```
 Shouldn't it display only by me calling the function without the need of echo or print_r?
```

If you call echo, print or print_r in your function (instead of assigning a return value) it will work. As it stands now your function returns a value but doesn't output anything.